# Given $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = x \ne 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = \pm\infty$ show that $\lim x_ny_n = \mp\infty$ when $x<0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given 
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = x \ne 0 \\
> \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = \pm\infty
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that for $x < 0$:
>   $$
> \lim x_ny_n = \mp\infty
> $$

I've started with the case when $\lim y_n = +\infty$:

$$
\forall \varepsilon >0\ \exists N_1 \in  \Bbb N:\forall n>N_1 \implies y_n > \varepsilon
$$

On the other hand the definition for $\lim x_n$ is going to be:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N_2 \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N_2 \implies |x_n - x| < \varepsilon
$$

That means we may choose some $N$ starting from which the following is true:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}: \forall n> N  \implies y_n > \varepsilon \ \text{and}\ |x_n - x| < \varepsilon
$$

So having that in mind we may consider the following system:
$$
\begin{cases}
|x_n - x| < \varepsilon \\
y_n > \varepsilon
\end{cases} \iff
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
-\varepsilon < &x_n -x < \varepsilon \\
-&y_n < -\varepsilon
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

So now if we multiply the inequalities one may obtain:
$$
-y_n(x_n - x) < -\varepsilon^2 \iff -x_ny_n + y_nx < \varepsilon^2 \iff x_ny_n>-\varepsilon^2 + y_nx
$$

At this point I got stuck, basically my idea was to utilize the definition of limits and then combine the two cases to arrive at a definition of a limit but for the sequence $x_ny_n$, but not sure how to proceed.

What steps should I take to prove what's in the problem section?

Comment: Is the $\varepsilon-\delta$ way obligatory?

Comment: @Rebellos not necessarily, that was just my try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lim y_n = +\infty$:

We want to show that for any $M>0$, we can find $N>0$, such that if $n>N$, then $x_ny_n < -M$.

We know that

$$
\forall M >0\ \exists N_{1,M} \in  \Bbb N:\forall n>N_{1,M} \implies y_n > M
$$

In paticular,

$$\exists N_{1,\frac{2M}{|x|}} \in  \Bbb N:\forall n>N_{1,\frac{2M}{|x|}} \implies y_n > \frac{2M}{|x|} \iff (-x)y_n > 2M \iff xy_n < -2M
$$

On the other hand the definition for $\lim x_n$ is going to be:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N_{2,\varepsilon} \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N_{2,\varepsilon} \implies |x_n - x| < \varepsilon
$$

In particular, $$ \exists N_{2,-\frac{x}2} \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N_{2,-\frac{x}2} \implies |x_n - x| < -\frac{x}2 \implies x_n < \frac{x}2.
$$

Hence for any $n> \max\left(N_{1,\frac{2M}{|x|}} , N_{2,-\frac{x}2}\right), x_ny_n < \frac{x}{2}y_n < \frac{(-2M)}{2}=-M$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the parts starting with "In particular, "?

Comment: I choose my particular $M$ to be $\frac{2M}{|x|}$. and for the seocnd part, I choose my particular $\varepsilon$ to be $-\frac{x}2$